# How can I create a WinForm app that just displays a NotifyIcon?

Tags: vb.net, notifyicon

I am pretty sure I've done this before, but I cannot remember how/where I found out how to do this.

I created a new WinForm application then dragged a notify icon onto my designer. I coded my desired functionality for the NotifyIcon's behavior inside the Form1.vb file.

I think I remember something about adding a module to the project, and setting the project to launch the aforementioned module instead of the form...but I can't figure out/recall how to keep the functionality I've coded into Form1.vb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/bc4556d5-3cb4-458b-96be-6f51c68700fd/) ? (first result on [google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=c%23+notifyicon+no+form&btnG=Search), I think I used it too in the past)